# Why can't the hyperplane H intersected with polyhedral set S contain any line...

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization

S is the polyhedral set

$ S  =  \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}  ; \mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{x} \ge \mathbf{0} \} $

and

$ H  :  \mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x} = \beta $

with

$ \min_S ( \mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x} )= \beta $

My textbook states that given the above, the set $S \cap H$ contains no line since $\mathbf{x}  \ge \mathbf{0}$ in $S$. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any line in $\mathbb R^2$ can be written as 
$$L = \left\{ \left(\begin{matrix}x \\ y\end{matrix}\right)  + t \left(\begin{matrix}u \\ v\end{matrix}\right) : t \in \mathbb R \right\}$$
where $u$ and $v$ are not both zero. For some choice of $t$, either $x+tu < 0$ or $y + tv < 0$. So $L$ contains a point $\mathbf x$ that does not satisfy $\mathbf x \geq 0$. So $L$ cannot be contained in $S$ (and hence not in $S\cap H$, no matter what $H$ is).

Comment: I just realised that I put R^2 where it should have been R^n. But I guess what you are saying is true for R^n as well. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it works just the same in $\mathbb R^n$.